# ¿Por qué mi Callback hecho en Kotlin genera un loop eterno que crashea my app?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, interfaz-gráfica, callback

Tengo que usar una interface en un fragmento, genero su instancia en la clase que le corresponde como contenedora, para iniciarla, y ahí es donde surge el problema… Un stack overflow por un eterno loop…

En el fragmento, tengo un *TextInputEditText*.. el cual tengo que ingresar un mensaje… X  mensaje… y presionar un Botón luego del input, y mostrar en un *TextView* mas abajo el input realizado.. nada mas que eso.

Si bien se que no seria necesario implementar una interface para dicha operación, el punto es empezar a implementar y familiarizarse con algunas herramientas de las mas usadas… con cosas fáciles…
aun así no lo logro conseguir…

Sé que mi problema esta en esta línea:

```
override fun getResult(input:String?):Result=getResult(textInputEditText.text.toString())
```

¿Cómo puedo arreglarlo? muchas gracias.

```
interface Result { val asString: String }
```

---

```
interface Calculator {fun getResult(input: String?): Result? }
```

---

```
class ComputeFragment @ContentView constructor() : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_task) {

    private var taskBinding: FragmentTaskBinding? = null
    private val calculator: Calculator? = null

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        if (context is Calculator) {
            calculator = context
        } else {
            throw RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must implement 
             Calculator interface")
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, 
        savedInstanceState:Bundle?): View {
        val binding = FragmentTaskBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        taskBinding = binding
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        taskBinding
                ?.buttonFirst
                ?.setOnClickListener {NavHostFragment.findNavController(this@ComputeFragment)
                 .navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment)
                }
        
        taskBinding
                ?.buttonCompute
                ?.setOnClickListener { v: View ->
                    if (calculator == null) {
                        Snackbar.make(v, R.string.please_implement, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        return@setOnClickListener

                    }else {
                        val result =calculator.getResult(taskBinding?.textInputEditText?.text.toString())
                        taskBinding?.result?.text = result?.asString

               }}}}
```

---

```
class TaskActivity : appCompatActivity() , Calculator {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_task)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar}
        }
        override fun getResult(input: String?): Result? = TaskActivity()
    override val asString: String
        get() = textInputEditText.text.toString()
       }}
```

Comment: @Israel-ICM gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: No hay nadie aca? ..pense que lo usaban mucho tambien... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estoy seguro de lo que intentas hacer pero el error está muy claro. Mira bien esta función

```
override fun getResult(input: String?): Result? = getResult(textInputEditText.text.toString())
```

Quitemos el parámetro para hacerlo más claro

```
fun getResult(): Result = getResult()
```

Ahora lo ves? La función es infinitamente recursiva. Se llama a sí misma una y otra vez y jamás obtendrá un resultado. Esa es la razón por la que obtienes un `StackOverflowError`.

Por lo que veo parece que quieres obtener un objeto que implemente la interfaz `Result`. Eso lo puedes hacer así

```
override fun getResult(input: String?) = object: Result {
    override val asString = input.toString()
}
```

Como ves, la sintaxis es bastante fea. Para mejorarla puedes convertir `asString` en un método y agregarle el modifier `fun` a la interfaz. Eso te permitirá crear la instancia así

```
fun interface Result {
    fun asString(): String
}

override fun getResult(input: String?) = Result { input.toString() }
```

aunque en tu caso talvez sea mejor crear una clase en vez de una interfaz

```
class Result(val asString: String)

override fun getResult(input: String?) = Result(input.toString())
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122492/discussion-on-answer-by-sinner-of-the-system-por-que-mi-callback-hecho-en-kotli).